# Insert Button into Word Document

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

Is it possible to insert a button into a word document and call as macro on click of this button. Please let me know if you have any similar ideas and also the procedure to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use VBA to do this, but it's pretty straight-forward.

There's an [MS knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246299) that describes exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to insert a Command button (as well as some other contorl like radio button etc) in Word Document.
Click on the Toolbar and enable Visual basic. You will get all control boxes, Select the Command Button. You can wirte the code into in the VBA script. This will get executed on click of the Command Button.