# Create radio buttons in word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

Is there a way to create a macro that, when activated, will present the user with some options, then call some other macro depends on what the user selected?

For example:

> Message box: Are you a male or female?
>
> Option 1: Male
>
> Option 2: Female

If the user selects "Male," execute macro A. If "Female," macro B.

Comment: There's a way. I'd first try [Google](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&q=Create+radio+buttons+in+word+VBA+site%3Amicrosoft.com).  There are dozens of examples with varying methods. Which one to use depends on your specific needs. Please check out "[help/on-topic]" -- SO is a place for professional *(or enthusiast!)* programmers to share advice when a problem's solution can't be found elsewhere; we like to see that some effort has been made in finding a solution before asking for help (on a _specific_ problem), so please [edit] your question to include details about what you've tried so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert Button into Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519737/insert-button-into-word-document)

Comment: Believe me, if I could understand the stuff written in all those threads on Google, I wouldn't bother asking. And what do you mean be specific? You want me to post my 2 macros in here? Would knowing what Macro A and Macro B looks like somehow make the fact that I don't know how to combine them together using radio buttons magically becomes clearer?

Comment: [so] is [not a good place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198358/370758) to learn the basics of programming, nor is it a "free coding service".  So I mean ***"specific"*** as in, if there is one *specific* line or section of code that you've written but isn't functioning properly, even after researching (**both** on [so] and elsewhere) to try to solve the problem yourself, then you can explain the issue in a Question here **and** include an **example** of your code as per "[mcve]" and also "[ask]".  I'll see if I can find you a simpler tutorial.

Comment: Actually it's not going to get any easier than the walk-through that @Displayname was kind enough to give you as an answer (worthy of an upvote at least?).    Here's a tutorial to help get you started:  [Coding For Option Buttons in VBA](https://www.homeandlearn.org/code_for_vba_option_buttons.html).  When you come across terms you don't recognize, google it like `<yourSearchTem> VBA Office` or my preference, `<yourSearchTerm> msdn vba`.

Comment: Weird, thought I did. Internet must have crapped out.

Comment: I am glad Nguyen Long asked the question, the google hits I got were for excel, and/or seemed more GUI centric.  This is the first hit I got that clearly incorporated actual VBA code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- while in Word UI press ALT F11 to open VBA IDE
- in main ribbon click Insert -> Userform

  and there you have a toolbox (if not, click View->ToolBox) and a Userform canvas
- from toolbox drag the option button icon and drop it into desired position of Userform. repeat it twice
- select first option button in the userform, click on its `caption` (some "OptionButton1" is shown as default) and edit it to "Male"
- do the same with second option button and edit its caption to "Female"
- click twice on the first option button on the userform

  it will show you

  ```
  Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

  End Sub
  ```

  then fill it as follows:

  ```
  Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
      macroA
  End Sub
  ```
- click twice on the second option button on the userform

  it will show you

  ```
  Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()

  End Sub
  ```

  then fill it as follows:

  ```
  Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
      macroB
  End Sub
  ```

this will get you started

Comment: well *someone's* gotta plus one that effort, so I will  :)

Comment: @ashleedawg, well someone's gotta thank you for that, so i will!